# Discord.js filter certain messages from fetched collection by emoji

Tags: node.js, collections, discord.js

So, I've created a delete command for my discordbot and so far it works almost perfectly fine.

```js
//stuff that checks permission and validation of inputs, not important now

                    const messages = await channel.messages.fetch({ limit: limiter });
                    const { size } = messages;
                    messages.forEach((message) => message.delete().catch((error) => logchannel.send(`Irgendwas ist schiefgelaufen ${message.author} :sob:`)));
                    channel.send(`${size} Nachrichten wurden gelöscht :wastebasket:`);
                    logchannel.send(`${size} Nachrichten wurden von ${message.member.displayName} aus ${channel} gelöscht.`);
             
//stuff sending out various errormessages for wrong permissions or inputs
```

so pretty straight forward: fetching messages, counting how many where fetched, deleting fetched messages, giving out logmessage "X amuout messages have been deleted from channel Y"

here comes the part where I don't know what to do: I want to filter out all messages that have a specific emoji as reaction, so that they can be skipped from deleting and give out a log messages like "Deleted X messages, Skipped Y messages" But I can't get anything like this work.
Only thing that worked was using messages.forEach(message) to outsource the deletion procss to another function that used an if statement to check every message one after another than deleting them or not. But that way, I couldn't get a proper count for the log message...

does anyone have an idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of doing this is to filter the reactions for each message you fetch:

```
const messages = await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: limiter});

// Use Array.from(); on the fetched messages to filter stuff easily
const filteredMessages = Array.from(messages.values()).filter(m => !m.reactions.resolve("your emote's ID"));
  
// Use bulkDelete(); to delete all messages at once. You're limited at 100 messages per bulk
// but you can bypass this with a while loop

message.channel.bulkDelete(filteredMessages, true);
```

You can get all the deleted messages with `filteredMessages.length`

and all the skipped messages by doing `messages.size - filteredMessages.length`